# I am trying to run the django wagtail demo app on google app engine. The app has been deployed and there are no errors on the GCP error reporting

Tags: django, google-app-engine, wagtail

I have allowed traffic on firewall port 8080, but I believe the issue lies in the app.yaml file and have added: `entrypoint: uwsgi --http-socket :8080 --wsgi-file main.py`, still the same error. My app.yaml is as below:

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: uwsgi --http-socket :8080 --wsgi-file main.py

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: /.*
  script: auto

env_variables:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: mysite.settings.production
```

Comment: The error message when I run the app is: Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: please add the error message as a part of your question instead of a comment

Comment: there's an official Wagtail app demo, I'd recommend using that one: https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-appengine-demo/

Comment: As @yedpodtrzitko, try using the official Wagtail app demo. 500 errors are common in App Engine, and one of the more common reason among many others could be that the request to a specific endpoint is not being handled anywhere in your code. We can't know for sure if this is the case, or something entirely different without further information. In the event that the issue persist through the usage of the official Wagtail demo, please provide a [Minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

GAE is looking for a main.py file. Do you have one? If so it should look like the following and remove your entrypoint entirely from the app.yaml.

app.yaml

```
runtime: python37

instance_class: F4_1G

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: mysite.settings.production
```

main.py

```
from mysite.wsgi import application

app = application
```